# CSS3 drop down menu styling

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I have these [drop down menus HERE](http://hauppauge.com/gaming/index2.htm) created using CSS on the Products, Support and Community nav links. The drop down menus have rounded corners on the bottom. The hover effect on the last link overrides the rounded corner and squares it off which I do not want. I would like the rounded corners to remain even on the hover on the last bottom link of the drop down. I think I need a property of overflow:hidden (?) on one of the styles but I've tried everything and I can't get it to work properly. What am I missing?

[The CSS is HERE.](http://hauppauge.com/css/gaming/nav-menu-gaming.css)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `border-radius` property doesn't change the boundaries of the `<ul>` element, rendering `overflow: hidden;` useless when the `<li>` elements get a background color.

My solution would be to apply `border-radius: 0px 0px 8px 8px;` to each of the bottom `<li>` elements in your drop-down menus.

Comment: That did it! I added the border-radius to the last-child and it works great now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `overflow: hidden;` on `.menu ul`

Answer (score 0):

CSS Border Radius is not inherited from its parent as you can see in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/sZtHk/

HTML

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.outer {
    background: #ff0000;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 24px;
}

.inner {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the borderadius that you have on your `<ul>` to the last link item.  If your hover state is controled by the `<a>` tag then you need to apply it there also.

```
.menu ul li:last-child { border-radius: 0px 0px 8px 8px; }
```

You may also, or alternatively need this:

```
.menu ul li:last-child a { border-radius: 0px 0px 8px 8px; }
```